# How to "safely" use cin with a char

Tags: c++

This seems like a dumb question, but I can't find much info about this.

My code takes user input, and only expects to receive `'t'` or `'f'`.

I have a hard time "protecting" the program from edge cases (ex: if the input contains multiple characters and/or spaces, it will loop through every `char` in the buffer until it finds `'t'` or `'f'`).

I understand that using `cin.fail()` only works for an `int`. Is there something similar that I could use for a `char`? I would like if something along the lines of this worked. I'm just having a hard time figuring out how to define an error/failure of `cin` in this case, and how to stop it from looping through the entire buffer.

```
char choice = '0';
while(choice != 't' && choice != 'f') {
    std::cout << "Is this answer true or false? (t/f) ";
    std::cin >> choice;
    
    if (error_with_input) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Error. char not entered. Please try again";
    }
}
```

Am I looking at this from the wrong point of view? Should I just make the `choice` variable a `string` instead of a `char`? I could then use `getline()`, test if `choice` has a length of 1, and if so then finally test if `choice` is either `'t'` or `'f'`. It seems a little inefficient, but maybe it's a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the input as a `std::string`, or at least as a `char[]`, is the right way to go.  Validate the input *after* you have read it in, not *while* you are reading it, eg:

```
string choice;
do {
    std::cout << "Is this answer true or false? (t/f) ";
    std::cin >> choice;
    
    if (choice != "t" && choice != "f") {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Error. char not entered. Please try again";
    }
    else {
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        break;
    }
}
while (true);
```

Comment: thanks so much! just out of curiosity, but what is the reason for calling the `ignore` function in the else (success) block

Comment: @Grant to ensure there is no lingering `\n` in the buffer before your next input. You didn't show your other code, so it's unknown if that `\n` might cause any issues for you, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/